# Insert into from 2 different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

**What I have:** I have 3 tables namely `CONTENT_MASTER`, `Account_Master` and `Content_Licenses`. The `Content_Licenses` table is used to store the licences of each content for different accounts. For example, I have the content called `myOldContent` with the following licences for each account:

```
Table: Content_Licenses

CL_AccountID    NoOfLicences
8               99
241             70
240             30
186             30
99              30
```

**What I want:**
For the below contents, I want to give same number of licences for each account :

```
Table: CONTENT_MASTER

CM_ID   CM_NAME
101    myNewContent1
102    myNewContent2
103    myNewContent3
```

**What I did:** I have written the below query to do this:

```
--Assign New components ID here and execute the query.
DECLARE @NewComponentID int

--Give license to new components
INSERT INTO CONTENT_LICENSES
                (CL_CM_ID
                ,CL_AccountID
                ,NoOfLicences)
            SELECT 
                @NewComponentID  --Want to fetch from CONTENT_MASTER table, instead of passing like this
                ,CL.CL_AccountID --Fetching from CONTENT_LICENSES table
                ,CL.NoOfLicences 
                FROM CONTENT_LICENSES CL 
                    INNER JOIN CONTENT_MASTER ON CM_ID = CL.CL_CM_ID
                WHERE CM_NAME = 'myOldContent'
```

**Problem**
I need to execute this query 3 times to give licences to 3 new components(i.e. by assigning the ID of the new component and executing it). Is there any alternative way to do this(without using cursor)?

Comment: Very confusing. The `CONTENT_LICENSES` sample shows a column named `CM_NAME`, but the query doesn't mention it. Instead it references a certain `CL_CM_ID` which is absent from the sample. And your description is not really helpful in resolving this confusion. So, how actually are the two tables related to each other? 2. What is `@NewComponentID`? Is it a parameter or is it just a variable that is calculated somewhere? If the latter, where/how is it calculated? 3. What is 'SomeName'? Is it a parameter or a fixed value? 4. Could you simply provide an example that would illustrate your goal well?

Comment: I have updated my question. Still if you have any confusion, pleas let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm still missing some bits, but so far it seems like you could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO CONTENT_LICENSES
    (CL_CM_ID
    ,CL_AccountID
    ,NoOfLicences)
SELECT 
    CM_NEW.CM_ID
    ,CL.CL_AccountID
    ,CL.NoOfLicences 
FROM CONTENT_LICENSES CL 
    INNER JOIN CONTENT_MASTER CM_OLD ON CM_OLD.CM_ID = CL.CL_CM_ID
    CROSS JOIN CONTENT_MASTER CM_NEW
WHERE CM_OLD.CM_NAME = 'myOldContent'
  AND CM_NEW.CM_NAME IN 
       ('myNewContent1'
       ,'myNewContent2'
       ,'myNewContent3')
```